# How do you add an eventlistener to a select element

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>NYC MTA</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">  
</head>
<body> 
<p>Line N</p>
```

Dropdown Button

```
<select id ="Select">
    <option id="Select">Times Square</option>
    <option id="34th">34th</option>
    <option id="28th">28th</option>
    <option id="23th">23th</option>
    <option id="23th">Union Square</option>
    <option id="8th">8th</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option id="Times Square">Times Square</option>
    <option id="34t">34th</option>
    <option id="28t">28th</option>
    <option id="23t">23th</option>
    <option id="23t">Union Square</option>
    <option id="8t">8th</option>
</select>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</html>

<script>
window.onload= function(){
    var lnListeners = function(){
        var ln = document.getElementById("Select");
        if(ln){
            ln.addEventListener('change', function(){alert("Do great stuff")});
        }
        lnListeners();
    }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`id="Select"` should only be in the `<select>` element, not the `<option>` element. IDs have to be unique.

And you need to call `lnListeners` outside the definition of the function.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var lnListeners = function() {
    var ln = document.getElementById("Select");
    if (ln) {
      ln.addEventListener('change', function() {
        alert("Do great stuff")
      });
    }
  };
  lnListeners();
};
```

```html
<select id="Select">
  <option id="Times Square">Times Square</option>
  <option id="34th">34th</option>
  <option id="28th">28th</option>
  <option id="23th">23th</option>
  <option id="23th">Union Square</option>
  <option id="8th">8th</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you just have to call the function lnListeners(), outside its scope.

```js
var lnListeners = function(){
        var ln = document.getElementById("Select");
        if(ln){
            ln.addEventListener('change', function(){alert("Do great stuff")});
        }
        
    }
lnListeners();
```

```html
<select id ="Select">
    <option id="Select">Times Square</option>
    <option id="34th">34th</option>
    <option id="28th">28th</option>
    <option id="23th">23th</option>
    <option id="23th">Union Square</option>
    <option id="8th">8th</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option id="Times Square">Times Square</option>
    <option id="34t">34th</option>
    <option id="28t">28th</option>
    <option id="23t">23th</option>
    <option id="23t">Union Square</option>
    <option id="8t">8th</option>
</select>
```